# how to wait for a promise to complete in node and firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to solve this issue for a long long time but unable to get it working.

```
g_globalList.once("value").then(function(tickList){
    var multiPaths = [];    
    tickList.forEach(function(ticker){
        ticker.val().forEach(function(path){
            multiPaths.push(path);
        });
    });
    return multiPaths;        
}).then(function(multiPaths){
    var myObj = {};
    multiPaths.forEach(function(path){
        var ticker = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1, 40);
        console.log("adding " + ticker);

        ****this is another promise and make my "myObj" to print blank****

        db.child("symbols/NSE/" +ticker).once('value').then(function(data){
            if(data.exists()){
                myObj[path] = data.val();
            }       
        });
    });
    return myObj;
}).then(function(myObj){
    console.log(myObj);
});
```

Is there anyway, I can call the last time "console.log(myObj)" after all promises are completed ?

Comment: You can use [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for wait all Promises resolve, check the example bellow (i not tested but maybe will give you an idea to resolve your problem):

```
var allPaths = [];

g_globalList.once("value").then(function(tickList){  
    return Promise.all(
   //map will create a array of the returned values (Promises in this case)
        tickList.map(function(ticker){
            return ticker.val();
        })
    );
}).then(function(values){//values represents all then results
    allPaths = values; //store for later all paths
    return Promise.all(
        //map will create a array of returned values (Promises in this case)
        values.map(function(path){

            var ticker = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1, 40);
            return db.child("symbols/NSE/" +ticker).once('value');
        })
    );
}).then(function(values){//values represents all then results
    var myObj = {}; //now lets create a obj

    for(var i = 0; i < allPaths.length; i++){ //foreach path
        var path = allPaths[i];
        //get the ticker name again
        var ticker = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1, 40);

        //check your data
        var data = values[i];
        if(data.exists()){
            //add to the obj
            myObj[path] = data.val();
        }      
    }
    //return the obj
    return myObj;
})
.then(function(myObj){
    //i hope its here now
    console.log(myObj);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use map on multiPaths instead of forEach. Return each  db.child call and wrap the map call with a Promise.all() and return that too.

Comment: Unfortunately the `Snapshot` returned by Firebase does not implement `map()`.